# Going back to track and field

Tags: track-and-field

I trained track and field when I was 13, but stopped at 15 due to excessive obligations. However, in the meantime I started karate, and it's really going well, but now I'm considering returning to track and field because I really love it and I have more time now.

The problem is, do I have a chance at becoming good in it? I'm 19 now, and while I was in T&F, my disciplines were the 100m and 200m dash. But I don't have to do the same disciplines. I was thinking switching to the 400m. And karate requires considerably less physical fitness than track and field, so my condition is probably far from perfect.

So, is there a possibility of me getting any good results in track and field after all these years? I don't have any sports injuries or health issues.

Comment: If you enjoy doing a sports, just go out and do it! You'll find out soon enough what level you can reach. I do not know what you consider "good results", but you are probably improving your PR quite a bit in the process, which should give you enough satisfaction to give it a try ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. You should try starting with some time of long-distrance run in order to improve your physical condition if needed, and then include some specific training progressively.

But unfortunately, the years of training you missed are the one during the end of the puberty where the physical performance improves a lot...

Do you want to go back to sprint for fun or for competitive purposes ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well, mainly because of fun - but the main point is whether I will be taken seriously in the local club or not. That is, will I ever be close to the ones training for a longer time.

Comment: It depends on two main factors : do these people in the club know you well, and do they know your sports situation ? Then, I don't think there is annything wrong in giving it a try, and if you are not close to them, try to train harder and more specifically. ;)